# Localstack on docker with .NET S3 SDK throws "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, localstack

I'm trying to setup [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) for a local S3 instance. I get an error when trying to perform any operation:

```
AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

The docker-compose is:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myapp.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp/api
    container_name: "myapp-api"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp.Api/MyApp.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=root
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=pass
  myapp.s3:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: "myapp-localstack"
    ports:
      - "14566:4566"
    environment: 
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - AWS_REGION=us-west-2
      - DEBUG=1
    user: root
```

`MyApp` is the name of the entire solution, `MyApp.Api` is an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project. There are no custom networks, all containers run on the default network created by docker-compose.

The code to interact with S3 looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestS3Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        using var client = new AmazonS3Client(new AmazonS3Config
        {
            ServiceURL = "https://myapp.s3:4566",
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2,
            ForcePathStyle = true
        });
        
        var bucket = await client.PutBucketAsync(new PutBucketRequest
        {
            BucketName = "myapp-test-bucket",
            BucketRegion = S3Region.EUW2
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        ... // snip
    }
}
```

The AWSSDK.S3 version is 3.3.113.2. Awaiting the `PutBucketAsync` task throws the aforementioned exception. All resources I was able to find tell me that the access key id and secret key can be anything, as long as they are non-empty, but it appears to be false.

Furthermore, I'm already running a container from the `amazon/dynamodb-local:latest` image, which requires the `root`/`pass` credentials defined in the environment variables and they work correctly. I can confirm that the credentials *are* loaded, both by the fact that local DynamoDB works and that manually instantiating `EnvironmentAWSCredentials` yields `root`/`pass`. Removing the environment variables from `myapp.api` throws a different exception related to the AWSSKD not being able to fetch any credentials (I don't have the .aws config file defined).

The `Dockerfile` for MyApp is the standard file generated for ASP.NET Core by Visual Studio that builds the project and starts `MyApp.Api.dll` as entrypoint.

Any solution that allows me to use the S3 bucket locally is appreciated, I don't really care for cleanness as long as it works, since it's for local development only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a discussion on few github issue threads regarding the same in localstack code base.

Use

```
ForcePathStyle = true
```

references:

https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/2092

https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/942#issuecomment-427327889